# Embedding chat on other sites, $A.util methods are undefined

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel, chat

I am trying to embed Live Agent chat on one of the intranet websites in our organization. I am getting the following error when I click on "Click to Chat".

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'isEmpty' of undefined or null reference
lightning.out.delegate.js (133,33)
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'compatPush' of undefined or null reference
aura_prod_compat.js (2474,5)
```

Because of these errors, the further chat window is not being loaded at all. Looks like it is conflicting with existing JS code on our intranet sites. Does the salesforce chat code dependent on any third party library?

This is proving to be a major blocker for me. This is happening on IE11. Can anyone help me with $A.util functionality? I want to debug it through and understand what exactly is happening.

A help would be really appreciated.

Rahul.

Comment: Looks like the scripts are accessing $A.util (which is a lightning code). Since the context is not lightning experience, $A is "undefined".... Have you generated this script from Chat Buttons in Salesforce?

Comment: Are you using it in lightning container? Can you post the problematic piece of code?

Comment: I am using the snap-ins scripts. Following this guide - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_get_code.htm&type=5

@the_phantom - $A is not undefined. the $A.util is undefined. And the scripts are automatically injected by esw.min.js so I have no control over it